# How to overload a Matlab operator in order for it to apply element wise to object arrays

Tags: matlab, operator-overloading

I'm trying to define a new class with the fields `object.DeltaI` and `object.E`, and I want to define the `-` operator for two object as:

```
new_obj.E=first_obj.E 
new_obj.DeltaI = first_object.DeltaI - second_obj.DeltaI
```

My problem is that I want this operator to work on a array of my class element wise. How do I define the operator to work element wise?

This is the class method function I wrote:

```
function r = minus(a,b)
    if length(a.E)==length(b.E) && sum(abs(a.E-b.E)<(10^-3))==length(a.E)
        r = [a];
        r.DeltaI = a.DeltaI - b.DeltaI;
    else
        error('a.E and b.E is not in the same size or E diffrance of more  than 10^-3')
    end
end
```

simple example:

the class definition is:

```
    classdef IV_class


        properties
            E
            I
        end

        methods
            function r = minus(a,b)
                r = a;
                r.I = a.I-b.I;
            end


        end

    end
```

now when I run this code:

```
    a(1) = IV_class;
    a(1).E = [1 2 3 4];
    a(1).I = [3 3 3 3];

    a(2) = IV_class;
    a(2).E = [1 2 3 4];
    a(2).I = [1 2 1 2];

    b(1) = IV_class;
    b(1).E = [1 2 3 4];
    b(1).I = [2 2 2 2];

    b(2) = IV_class;
    b(2).E = [1 2 3 4];
    b(2).I = [1 1 1 1];

    a(1)-b(1)
    % i get the proper answer: 
    % ans = 

     %IV_class with properties:

        %E: [1 2 3 4]
        %I: [1 1 1 1]
    a-b
    % i get error:
    % Error using  - 
    %Too many input arguments.
    %
    %Error in  -  (line 13)
    %            r.I = a.I-b.I;
```

its works when i'm doing a(1)-b(1)
but not in the case of a-b

Comment: When I make a tiny class of your code, the only error that is thrown is about the `&&` in the `if` statement. Try changing the `&&` to `&`.

Comment: Are you saying the operator doesn't work by default element-wise on object arrays? Could you provide a [minimal and self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: Also when you have two object arrays, use `.-` to be sure.

Comment: I added simple code to demonstrate the issue

Comment: @Argyll `.-` is not an operator in MATLAB.

Comment: Just some comments on your code: Instead of `sum(abs(a.E-b.E)<(10^-3))==length(a.E)`, use `any` or `all`. For example: `~all(abs(a.E-b.E)<1e-3)`. Also, use the `e` notation rather than `10^`, it's more readable. And the brackets in `r = [a]` don't do anything. This is just `r = a`. But you're better off defining the function as `a = minus(a,b)`. Then if you call it with `x=x-y` it won't make a copy of `x`, it will work in-place.

Comment: @AmirRaicher: I see. I wonder why that is. You may have to use `bsxfun` or `arrayfun`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
classdef IV_class
        properties
            E
            I
        end

        methods (Static)
            function r = minus_(a,b)
                r = a;
                r.I = a.I-b.I;
            end
        end
        methods
            function r = minus(a,b)

                for c = 1:numel(a)
                    r(c) = IV_class.minus_(a(c),b(c));
                end
            end


        end

end
```

Of course, you should add tests to check whether `a` and `b` have the same length, you should allocate `r` and so on.